# BACKGROUND VIDEO IN MAIN ACTIVITY

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a video in the background on the main screen and put some buttons over it. The problem is that is showing me a white background and I haven't set that. If anyone can help me find the solution I'll appreciate. I tried so many things and It's not playing the video...

This is the Java Code

```
package co.siriusapps.aviation;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.view.View;

public class StarterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private VideoView videoview;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);

    VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mainvideo);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);

  videoview.start();

    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            View placeholder = (View) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);

            placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="co.siriusapps.aviation.StarterActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/BankList"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You have not provided constraints to parent `FrameLayout` of `VideoView`.

Comment: Your app is going to be very heavy, on lower end devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the video view to 0dp height and width.  And its inside a frame layout.  That means it will literally have no size, so you won't see anything.  There's no need for the frame layout, make it fill_parent width and height and put it directly in the constraint layout

Also, no need for additional constraints on it.  Fill_parent in both directions is sufficient in and of itself.